# find z such that $\vec{u}$ and $\vec{v}$ are linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is given as, "Determine the values of z such that the vectors $\vec{u} = \pmatrix{-1\\z}$ and $\vec{u} = \pmatrix{z\\-1 + z}$ are linearly independent.

Here is my work...

$\pmatrix{-1 & z& \\ z& (-1 + z)& }$

$\pmatrix{-1 & z& \\ 0& (z^2+z-1)& }$

therefore, $z^2+z-1 \neq 0$

$z \neq \frac{1}{2}(-1-\sqrt{5})$

$z \neq \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{5} + 1)$

Does that seem right?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: I don't get how you get to your second parenthesis from the first. Linear independency means non-zero determinant, and you got it right.

Comment: @mbaitoff, he multiplied first row to $z$ and added it to 2nd row.

Comment: It is good except you mess up the quadratic formula slightly. The answer is $z\neq \frac{1}{2}(-1\pm\sqrt{5})$. Note the $1$ does not change signs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
z^2 + z - 1 \ne 0 \Rightarrow \\ 
z^2 + z +\frac{1}{4} \ne \frac{5}{4} \Rightarrow \\
\left(z+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \ne \frac{5}{4} \Rightarrow\\
z \ne -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}, z \ne -\frac{1}{2} - \frac{\sqrt{5}}{2} 
$$